# Changing the visibility of layers dynamically in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, postgis, geoserver

I am using openlayer 5.3.3 in my react application. I am trying to change the visibility of the layers dynamically when the user clicks the options of layers.

```
    var resolutions = new Array(14);
      var matrixIds = new Array(14);
      var size = getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
    for (var z = 0; z < 14; ++z) {
        // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
        resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
        matrixIds[z] = "EPSG:4326:" + (z - 1);
      }
    const constructSource = (layer) => {
        var source = new WMTS({
          url: geoserverUrl,
          layer:layer,
          matrixSet:"EPSG:4326",
          format:"image/png",
          projection: getProjection("EPSG:4326"),
          tileGrid: new WMTSTileGrid({
            origin: getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
            resolutions: resolutions,
            matrixIds: matrixIds,
          }),
          style: "",
          wrapX: true,
        });
        return source;
      };
      var layersource = constructSource("layers:myLayer");

     var layer1 = new TileLayer({
        opacity: 0.7,
        source: layersource,
        visible: false,
      });
    var view = new View({
        center: [29.94049072265625, -3.438720703125],
        zoom: 8,
        projection:getProjection("EPSG:4326"),
      });


      useEffect(() => {
        map.current = new Map({
          view,
          layers: [layer1],
          target: "map",
        });
      }, [map]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.selectedLevel === "level2") {
          console.log("check visibility here", layer1.getVisible()); // this results false
          layer1.setVisible(true);
          console.log("check visibility here 2", layer1.getVisible()); //this results true
        }
      }, [props.selectedLevel]);

return (
    <div
      id="map"
      ref={(el) => (map = el)}
      style={{ height: "100%", width: "80em" }}
    ></div>
  );
```

layer1.getVisible gives true but the layer is not shown. 
layer1.setVisible(true) work if it is set on first reload.

Comment: My spidey sense tells me that you want to call `new Map` once in your application/per component. Right now you are creating a new map in the first every time the `map` variable changes in the first `useEffect()` call. What does `map` hold and how often does it change? Have you tried calling `useEffect` with an empty list (instead of `[map]`)?

Comment: yes there is no change. still the same

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with react, but to me it seems as the reference to `var layer1` is lost once added to the map. Therefore, changing the visibility of the variable does not affect the layer inside the map.

Did you try setting the visibility by getting your layer from the `map` object using [`map.getLayers()`](https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getLayers)? This will return a collection of layers associated with the map. For the sake of simplicity I will assume `layer1` is the only layer that is being added to the map. In this case, `getLayers()` will give you an array of one layer `[layer]`. You can set the visibility using `map.getLayers()[0].setVisible(true/false)`. If you have more layers, you would want to loop through your collection and set visibility based on a layer id.

Also, (as mentioned in the comments), you are recreating the map every time `useEffects()` is called. There is no need for that. Just create the map once. The OpenLayers API provides enough [methods](https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html) to access and modify the map object, including the layers associated with it.

Comment: yes i have also tried that! its no use. I can change the visibility outside of useEffect only.